# Trouble with USB video on Dell XPS 13 with 16.04

Tags: usb, display, dell, laptop, monitor

I just got a Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 16.04 pre-installed, and I'm still working out all of the new-computer kinks. I'm using a Thunderbolt docking station (StarTech) to connect my peripherals. Keyboard, mouse, etc. are all fine, but the monitor is tripping me up.

I'm using a Samsung monitor (S27C230B) that only has RGB and DVI inputs, and the StarTech dock only has DisplayPort and USB-C outputs. I've got a DisplayPort-to-DVI cable, and was able to connect the monitor to my old Lenovo laptop (which has a DisplayPort plug on it, but no Thunderbolt) without any trouble. When I plug it into the dock, though, I see nothing. Neither the computer nor the monitor seems to acknowledge that there is a connection.

I tried installing the DisplayLink Ubuntu drivers (http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu), but I can't really tell whether anything happened as a result of this. Their support site (https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649) shows the ouptput one ought to see in the terminal, and I'm missing the last two lines ("Starting DLM upstart job" and "displaylink start/running, process 3397").

If it helps, my `lsusb` output is:

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 058f:9410 Alcor Micro Corp. Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:0939 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0022 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0a2 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58f4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any ideas about how I can debug this? Would I be better off with a USB-C-to-DVI cable instead?

Thanks!

Comment: is the adapter active or passive? If it's passive, that would explain why it isn't working. Some machines are able to handle passive adapters because they have integrated clocking to operate in sort of a legacy mode. Something doing it over usb-c is unlikely to have that particular feature--I'm not entirely sure it even has the correct required pinout to make that work.

Comment: Yeah, I talked to someone at StarTech support and they told me to try either an active DP-DVI adapter or a USB-C-DVI adapter. I ordered something that I should be able to try out tonight.